# Shopping Cart Price Rule exclude parent products categories

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

Please help.

We add all our products so that only the parent products get assigned into categories. I need to add a shopping cart price rule to exclude certain categories i.e:

If ALL of these conditions are TRUE :
 Category is not one of [category IDs]

The problem is the child products don't belong to any categories so the rule doesn't get applied to the cart.

Any solutions????

Answer (score 0):

You need to select "product attribute combination" from conditions section drop down and you can add any category or subcategory equal or not equal conditions like below

If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ANY  of these conditions true: 
Category  is  ...

Comment: Does not apply to child products if you select the parent's category

Comment: You need to select parent as well as subcategories

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand could you be more specific?

Comment: You can select parent category and subcategories to apply these rules.